# Visual studio 2013 sdk official not officially available anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The official visual studio 2013 sdk download is not available from microsoft anymore 
:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441(v=vs.120).aspx

It is permanently offline (official download link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758)

Does somebody have the installer file? Even web installer will do i think, ressources are still available i assume

Comment: have you downloaded the file so that I can delete it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I additionally found out that it is still officially available for MSDN subscribers with a free Visual Studio subscription (https://www.visualstudio.com/de/dev-essentials) in the download section

Comment: nice to hear this. post this as answer. I'll delete my link now.