# Where can I download SDK for visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, installation

I have Visual Studio 2013 and want to install SDK for it.

Can't add 2015 SDK because it is part of VS 2015 installation, I couldn't find a stand alone installation.

[2013 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758) was removed from the official site.

It is also not contained in my installation package for VS.

Thanks

Comment: this was already [asked some days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44544396/1466046). check the comment for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please navigate to this: [Download older versions of VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) and click the ‘**Join now for free’** to sign in with your Microsoft account, if you are not a subscriber. Then confirm to join the VS Dev Essential if you have not joined before. Click ‘**Downloads’** and search with the keyword ‘Visual Studio 2013 SDK’, you will get the download link as below: 
[image]

Comment: Note that you must name the download ``VSSDK_FULL.EXE`` or it won't run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from excellent answer by Sara Liu - MSFT, I was able to find a *Visual Studio 2013 SDK - Microsoft Go!* download page from google. The direct link was [go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832352](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832352) and it downloaded a +13Mb `vssdk_full.exe`